# Rooted HD2 shows unrooted as status

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, rooting, unrooting, htc-hd2

I have successfully installed Android Gingerbread 2.3.2 on my HTC HD2 device. While installing the DSTV app, I first  tried to unroot it for sometime using the VoodooOTA Rootkeeper app. The problem is that the status of HD2 shows unrooted when using the VoodooOTA Rootkeeper  but rooted when trying the DSTV app.

Is anyone having this kind of problem and how to go about it? Thanks

Anyone?
Any help?

Comment: Try SuperUser and see what it says.  You'll also want to check `/system/bin/` and `/system/xbin/` for `su` (one may be a symlink) and remove it if the unrooter didn't do so.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. The supersuser shows 0 entry. Trying now to figure out how to access the system files. Will get back to u soon

Comment: I am using Droid Explorer to access the root file of my phone. I found the su file in systems/bin but not in systems/xbin. I realize that su is an executable file. Is there any way to check why my phone is recognized as rooted by some apps and unrooted by others?